# Need SQL Query Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, join, laravel

I'm a bit rusty on SQL and just need a little help thinking this through.

Let's say I have tables for Applications, Ratings and Admins. The idea is that each of the Admins can mark down their Rating for each Application. A Rating has foreign keys for admin_id and application_id.

For the query, I'd like to select all Applications that any particular Admin has not yet rated. Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah that seems fine - What's the actual question?

Comment: Please show what you think the SQL you look like.

Comment: Please post your table structure, sample data and sample output.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` perhaps? It basically just returns all rows where there exists no rating from the admin with the particular id.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM applications a
LEFT JOIN ratings r 
  ON a.application_id = r.application_id
 AND r.admin_id = ?
WHERE r.admin_id IS NULL
```

I'd write a fiddle, but SQLfiddle is tired again.

Comment: This is the correct answer, tested in Navicat, but I just need to translate it into laravel's Eloquent syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ap.application_id FROM application ap,rating r,admin ad WHERE ad.admin_id=r.admin_id AND ap.application_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT application_id FROM rating) AND ad.admin_id=5;
```

Does this give the answer?
Haven't tried it myself though, but i think it will..